# Centering cards

Tags: html, centering, card

I am having trouble centering these cards:

[image: Having trouble centering these cards]

I searched on google and stack overflow, but cannot find the solution. I'm trying to center these cards but cannot, I've tried display flex, justify-content center, and align-items center with no luck along with many other solutions posted online but still can't fix it.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Please post code to reproduce your issue and not just an image.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If you did really set `align-items` and `justify-content`, I suspect you did not set the `width` of the container element to stretch, hence, it is hugging the contents and sticking to the left.

Try as below:

```css
.container {
  /*I suspect this has not been set*/
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.card {
  /*placeholder width & height*/
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>

</div>
```

Also this is a bit irrelevant, but are your single cards `cards` and the container `card`? Why? I think it's much more intuitive if it was multiple `card`s inside a `cards` container.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! This means a lot! I tried display grid and margin auto on the parent div and it worked! I'm glad you commented this though because I completely forgot setting width to auto was a thing which helps now. Thank you again stranger.